# Stop screen capture on UWP app in TaskView of Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I stop screen capturing on my UWP app by

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
```

However, the app still shows its preview on Taskview of Windows 10
[image]

Can someone let me know how to disable the app's preview on Task view

This is the current TaskView 
[image]

and this is how I need it
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing an app's thumbnail looks like a system behavior, and I don't know how to disable it.

But since the capture only happens when the user presses `Alt+Tab` or clicks the task switch button on the task bar, there is a chance to cover the app with an overlay before system takes a screen capture of the app.

First add an opaque overlay, and set its initial visibility as `Collapsed`.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="Your controls here!" />
    <Grid Background="Black" x:Name="overlay" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

Then register a handler for app window's Activated event,

```
Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
```

Display/Hide the overlay when window is deactivated/activated,

```
private void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WindowActivationState == Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
    {
        overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it has other issues. Like if the user clicks on the taskbar or clicks on the clock, the app gets deactivated. Afterward, the user has to explicitly click on the app to Activate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking of displaying the overlay temporarily, just for the capture, and hide the overlay after the capture is done. In debugging, I found it is not only capturing a thumbnail _once_, it is actually a live video recording of the app window! So I think the Windows 10 OS is making it quite hard for your requirement, [this](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/disable-taskbar-thumbnail-previews-windows/) does not work on Windows 10 either.